# How to populate the BST and also print it in Inorder way

Tags: java, static, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying this code to populate the BST and then print it in the InOrder traversal format. But the root node is not getting populated compiling wihtout any error and Output is : "root is empty", so how to correct this code so that my BST gets populated in the Node root.

I tried to make Node root as static I thought it might be the case that root node might not be accessible from each method but it is not working, tried to change the name of the Node but it is also not working.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Node{
    int data; Node left; Node right;
    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;

    }
}
public class insert_tree {
    static Node root;   

     insert_tree() //constructor
     { 
        root = null; 
     } 
    public void addNode(int value) { // public method is called by the object and this public method calls the private method in which the root is also passed.
        root = add(root, value);
    }
    private Node add(Node node, int value) {
        if(node == null) {
            return node;
        }
        if(value < node.data) {
            node.left = add(node.left, value);
        }       
        else if(value > node.data) {
            node.right = add(node.right, value);
        }
        else {
            return node;
        }
        return node;
    }

    private void inOrder(Node node) {
//      node = root;
        if(node != null) {
            inOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            inOrder(node.right);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("root is empty");
        }
        //return null;
    }
    public void inorder() {
        inOrder(root);
    }
   private void printRoot(Node root) {
      System.out.println(root.data);
   }
   public void print() {
      printRoot(root);
   }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        insert_tree obj = new insert_tree();
        obj.addNode(20);
        obj.addNode(14);
        obj.addNode(25);
        obj.addNode(10);
        obj.addNode(16);
        obj.addNode(25);
        obj.addNode(21);
        obj.addNode(30);
        //printing the tree
        obj.inorder();



    }
}
```

The output should be the inorder traversal of the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void addNode(int value) { // public method is called by the object and this public method calls the private method in which the root is also passed.
    root = add(root, value);
}
private Node add(Node node, int value) {
    if(node == null) {
        node = new Node(value);
    }
    else if(value == node.data) {
        node.data = value;
    }
    else if(value < node.data) {
        node.left = add(node.left, value);
    }
    else {
        node.right = add(node.right, value);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the 2nd if statement (value == node.data) ? If that statement was true you would always be setting node.data to its already existing value, wouldn't you be ?